# How to assign the datetime of saturday 10pm in a variable

Tags: python-3.x

Using python code, I want to check if the file latest time stamp is greater than Saturday 10 pm and then proceed with the process. Have a variable which holds file time stamp. Need a variable which have the saturday 10 pm timestamp. The job can run anytime between saturday 10 pm to Monday 8 am.

Comment: Check the `datetime` library.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
hour = today.hour

# use datetime.today().weekday() if you want to start Monday from 0
current_day = datetime.today().isoweekday()

if current_day == 6 and hour > 22:
    pass  # run_job()
if current_day == 7:
    pass  # run_job()
if current_day == 1 and hour < 8:
    pass  # run_job()
```